# Using GridLayout to display the sam size of Cardviews in every device

Tags: android, android-studio, androidx, android-gridlayout

I use GridLayout to display 4 card views within an activity but the problem is that the sizes change between different device sizes. How can I use GridLayout to display the same size of card views on every device? Right now they get scratched.

Here is a picture I want to display the Cardviews on every device:

[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhDob.png)

[Picture where the size of card views changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1QiJ.png)

Here is my GridLayout:

```
<androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="6"
    app:columnCount="2"
    app:rowCount="2"
    app:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
    app:columnOrderPreserved="false"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/btn_kategorie_1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"
        app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:elevation="7dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Geschichte"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@mipmap/geschichte"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/btn_kategorie_2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"
        app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:elevation="7dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Sport"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@mipmap/sport"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        </LinearLayout>


    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/btn_kategorie_3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"
        app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:elevation="7dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Musik"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@mipmap/musik" />
```

```
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/btn_kategorie_4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:elevation="7dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Wirtschaft"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@mipmap/geld"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

        </LinearLayout>


    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout>
```

Comment: try adjustViewBounds attribute in your ImageViews, maybe it'll help

Answer (score 0):

There are two solution here

- 1st use recyclerView adapter and make only one card view and give gird layout manger to recyclerView
- 2nd if go from this code then Use this library

> implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'